# UICollectionViewCell data updating with every reload call

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I need cells in a UICollectionView which will either show text or an image.

I am implementing this by creating my own UICollectionViewCell having two properties - UIImage property and NSString property.

Depending on which property the caller sets, I show either the image or the text. The calling collectionview is also reusing the cells by using :

```
cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

But whenever I reload the collectionview in my code the cells get all messed up - they show empty buttons. What am I doing wrong? Let me know if you need me to post any other specific code piece. I didn't want to clutter my question with useless code.

In my CollectionViewCell, I am resetting both the label and the image:

```
-(void) prepareForReuse {
    [super prepareForReuse];
    [_button setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [_button setImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [_button removeTarget:nil action:NULL forControlEvents:UIControlEventAllEvents];
}
```

cellForItemAt code:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    MyCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSInteger position = indexPath.row;

    long listIdx = position - 1;

    if (listIdx == ADD_ICON_INDEX) {

        UIImage * addImage = [self _getAddImage];
        [cell setButtonImage:addImage target:self action:@selector(_addButtonClicked:)];
        cell.button.tag = listIdx;
        return cell;

    }

    NSString *title= _visibleButtons[listIdx];

    [cell setButtonTitle:title target:self action:@selector(_buttonClicked:)];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.button.tag = listIdx;


    return cell;

}
```

Comment: Show your `cellForItemAt` code

Comment: Added the code for cellForItemAt